# ksh shell script to find first occurence of _ in string and remove everything until that

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

Im New To  Shell Scripting.Using KSH Shell. Could you please help me in this.

My string is like errorfile101_ApplicationData_2_333.txt. I want to  remove everything until the first occurence of _.

My output should be ApplicationData_2_333.txt

Comment: We can help you but you need to ask a specific question. Not just "here is what I want, please do it for me". Make an attempt, show the code and ask a *specific* question related to the code that will help you get past the thing you are blocked on.

Comment: New at shell-scripting? When you have a choice, you might want to use `bash` and not `ksh`. Not needed for this problem but giving you access to more builtins (things done easy and quick in bash and difficult in ksh).

Comment: Thanks Kaylum , Next time I would definitely post the code that I attempted.

Comment: Thanks Walter for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy one, assuming you can assign your string to a variable, i.e.

```
str="errorfile101_ApplicationData_2_333.txt"
echo ${str#*_}
```

**output**

```
ApplicationData_2_333.txt
```

The `#` operator in `${str#*_}` means remove the following pattern from the left of the variable's value.

There is also `##`, which removes the longest match from the left, which would give you

```
333.txt
```

There are also similar removal operators for working from the right side of the string, `%` and a longest match (from right) with `%%`.

All versions of `ksh` (and bash, and other shells) support these operators. (sorry if this is the wrong term).

Versions of `ksh93` and greater (`bash`, `zsh` and probably others) also support a `sed` like pattern match/sub value like

```
echo ${str/*_/xx}
#----------|--|>replacement
#----------> pattern to match
```

**output**

```
xx333.txt
```

which means that `/` works like `sed` matching the longest possible string.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cut` command:

```
echo "errorfile101_ApplicationData_2_333.txt" | cut -d"_" -f2-
```